# Slow JSON generation time in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, postgresql, activerecord, globalize

I am currently trying to render a fairly large JSON, from a database model, with some translations using Globalize.

It seems the problem is at the rendering process, not at loading the model and his translations.

```
Completed 200 OK in 1141ms (Views: 990.6ms | ActiveRecord: 16.7ms)
```

The final JSON size is about 18k lines and it takes around ~2-3 seconds to complete the generation.

I tried to switch to `oj`, but I did not see any significant performance, is this normal ?

Also, I tried the [`surus`](https://github.com/JackC/surus) gem, which works great (around 90ms), but it does not seems to support Globalize (which is normal, because it is working at the database level directly, no through ActiveRecord).

I was wondering if there is any other things I could use/check/try to improve the generation time ? Yes I could use some kind of caching, but I would like to avoid it, unless it is truly necessary.

**Edit**: We are still using Rails 3.x, I don't know if there is any improvement on this topic in Rails 4.x.

Comment: Are you sure the JSON generation is the problem? Last time I looked at Globalize it was doing insane things like hitting the database over and over again rather than using JOINs.

Comment: 18KLOC for json is really large, but as @muistooshort mentioned, finding out exactly what's causing the huge delay might be a useful thing to do here. I would try [something really simple](http://www.skorks.com/2010/03/timing-ruby-code-it-is-easy-with-benchmark/) to find out which part of the code is taking a long time.